# javascript click event subscription in appended html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this javascript code that appends html code into a tag:

```
                var html ='<ul class="nav well-tabs well-tabs-inverse mb10">';
                html +='<li class="active"><a id="#tab_'+this.my.user+'" data-toggle="tab">'+this.my.user+'</a></li>';
                var users = this.my.community_users;
                for (i=0;i<users.length;i++) {
                    if (users[i].user != this.my.user)
                    html +='<li><a id="#tab_'+users[i].user+'" data-toggle="tab">'+users[i].user+'</a></li>';
                };
                html +='</ul>';
                $(html).appendTo("#Dashboard");
```

I want to capture the any tab click event and alert the id of the tab being activated by the click. If I simply add this code after the previous javascript code

```
$('a[data-toggle=tab]').click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

this is not working. On the other hand if I settimeout after the second it works:

```
                 setTimeout(function(){ 
                $('a[data-toggle=tab]').click(function(){
                    alert(this.id);
                });
            }, 1000);
```

I don't like much this to settimeout so what would be a cleaner solution to this? I guess the event suscription is being done before the html code is appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically created elements in jQuery you should use a static parent to select the dynamic element, in your case an example can be:

```
$('#Dashboard').on('click', 'a[data-toggle=tab]', function(e){
  //your code here
});
```

OR even the document itself

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle=tab]', function(e){
  //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use delegate() or on() for this purpose

see  [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Note: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method

In your case you are not giving selection with respect to parent

```
$("parent_selection").on('click', 'actual_element' ,function(){});
```

your case

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle=tab]', function(e){

});
```